# Semigroups of matrices closed under conjugate transposition

Tags: rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, matrix-theory

An *involution semigroup* or *$\star$-semigroup* is a unary semigroup $\langle S,{\cdot}\,,{}^\star\rangle$ that satisfies the equations $$ (x^\star)^\star = x \quad \text{and} \quad (xy)^\star = y^\star x^\star. $$ Common examples include $\langle M_n(\mathbb{R}),{\cdot}\,,{}^T\rangle$ and $\langle M_n(\mathbb{C}),{\cdot}\,,{}^*\rangle$. An *inverse $\star$-semigroup* is a $\star$-semigroup that satisfies the equations $$xx^\star x = x \quad \text{and} \quad xx^\star yy^\star = yy^\star xx^\star. {\tag1\label{1}}$$

Using standard methods from linear algebra, it is quite easy to show:

- Every periodic sub-$\star$-semigroup of $\langle M_n(\mathbb{C}),{\cdot}\,,{}^*\rangle$ is an inverse $\star$-semigroup.

In other words, every periodic sub-$\star$-semigroup of $\langle M_n(\mathbb{C}),{\cdot}\,,{}^*\rangle$ satisfies the equations \eqref{1}. Recall that a $\star$-semigroup $\langle S,{}\cdot\,,{}^\star\rangle$ is *periodic* if $(\forall a \in S)(\exists m \geq 1) \ a^{2m} = a^m$.

A colleague suggested that this may be a special case of some known general result, probably in operator theory. Therefore, I would like to ask if anyone is aware of a reference for the above result.

Comment: $A \approx B$ just means the equation $A = B$. I have replaced every $\approx$ by $=$.

Comment: Thanks! I have deleted my earlier notational comment.

Comment: As you may know—and as is possibly irrelevant here, but it's the first thing I thought when I saw the title—an (adjectives omitted since I don't know the right ones) subgroup of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb R)$ is reductive if and only if it is preserved by (a conjugate of) the inverse transpose.

Comment: As the guilty colleague, to not replicate work the point here is that every element of $S$ is a partial isometry due to the periodicity and it is an old result of Halmos and Wallen that the product of two partial isometries $a,b$ on a Hilbert space is another partial isometry iff $a^*abb^*=bb^*aa^*$ and so the question is basically has it been observed before that a periodic $\ast$-semigroup acting on a Hilbert space is automatically a $\ast$-semigroup of partial isometries.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg but why does it consists of partial isometries? For instance a nonzero nilpotent element is periodic but is not a partial isometry.

Comment: @YCor, it needs to be a *-semigroup so the nilpotent product with its * must still be in your semigroup.  This is not typically the case.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg could you be more precise? Do you mean that $a,aa^*, a^*a$ periodic implies $a$ partial isometry, or something of this flavor?

Comment: @YCor, $\ast$-subsemigroup will span a $C^*$-algebra in $M_n(\mathbb C)$ and hence be semisimple but the algebra spanned by the semigroup generated by a nilpotent element will not be semisimple.

Comment: @YCor, exactly.  Look at the eigenvalues of $aa^*$, but anyway as the OP said the argument is elementary but was this already observed?

Comment: @Ycor, I was saying the ordinary algebra is not semisimple and that is why being closed under * is important.  That's why I didnt say *-algebra

Comment: I don't know of a reference off the top of my head, not do I immediately recognize the result, but two people who might be worth consulting are Laurent Marcoux or Heydar Radjavi (both at U. Waterloo)

Comment: @YemonChoi Thanks; I asked but neither of them was aware of a reference.